# Python write binary image(PNG) data to file

Tags: python, file-io, png, python-requests

I am using the `requests` module to connect to a php script which returns a PNG image. If I do so :

```
import requests
r=requests.get("http://location/script.php", cookies=cookies)
fp = open("image.png", "wb")
fp.write(r.text) #r.text is the binary data for the PNG returned by that php script
fp.close()
```

But it gave a UnicodeEncodeError while writing, so I used `fp.write(r.text.encode("utf-8"))` instead of `fp.write(r.text)`.
And the file was created, but I'm not able to view it in an image viewer(it gives an error). However, if I right-click and save the PNG returned by that script in Firefox, I can view it in the same image viewer after it's saved. So I'm guessing there is a problem with the way I'm writing that image data to a file.
Is there some other way I could do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.text` is **not** the binary data. That attribute gives you the decoded text, a Unicode value.

You'd want to use `r.content` instead, or *stream* the image to a file setting `stream=True` and copying from the `r.raw` file object.